# How can render many to many tags in html in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have created a Tag model and it is a foreign key to Blog model.But I can't render the tags in html template.

Here is the Tag model

```
class Tag(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "tag"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the Blog model

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='titel')
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, verbose_name='tag')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In my Views.py

```
class BlogDetailView(View):

    def get(self, request, news_pk):
        blog = Blog.objects.get(id=int(news_pk))
        title = news.title
        tags = blog.tag
        return render(request, 'news_detail.html',
                      {
                          'title': title,
                          'tags': tags
                      })
```

And in the detail html:
I tried two way to render the tag ,both fails.

1.

```
{% for tag in tags %}

<span>{{ tag.name }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

This way it comes out nothing.

2.

```
    <span>{{ tags.values }}</span>
```

it comes out with many things like this

```
 <QuerySet [{'id': 4, 'name': 'eatting'}, {'id': 5, 'name': 'drinking'}, {'id': 7, 'name': 'playing'}]>
```

3. {{ tags.values_list }}

it comes out like

```
 <QuerySet [(4, 'eating'), (5, 'drinking'), (7, 'playing')]>
```

Any friend can tell me the right way to render the tags of a blog in html?Thanks very much!

Comment: Ideally, your first attempt should work. Can you please check if Meta class is creating some issue( because of same variable name)? Also, which django version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 Django 2.0

Comment: Actually I used another name for verbose_name.    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "标签"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

Comment: Doesn't look anything wrong to me. Can you please check what's there in html using chrome debugger?

Comment: I made it!Look at my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the views.py I used **annotate**

```
class BlogDetailView(View):

    def get(self, request, news_pk):
        blog = Blog.objects.get(id=int(news_pk))
        title = news.title
        tags = blog.tag.annotate(blog_count=Count('blog'))
        return render(request, 'news_detail.html',
                      {
                          'title': title,
                          'tags': tags
                      })
```

And then in the template:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
<span>{{ tag.name }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```